# Ubuntu 22.04 only boots in recovery mode, missing AMD iGPU drivers (Laptop)

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, graphics, amd-graphics

I have an Acer laptop (Model: NX.KKZEZ.00C) with the following components:

1. CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7840U
2. RAM: 32 GB
3. SSD: 1000 GB
4. GPU: AMD Radeon 780M (Integrated Graphics)

I shrank the C Volume by 100 GB and installed Ubuntu in that new partition, using the normal "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11" option.

Now, I can't directly boot into Ubuntu. When I try, I only get a black screen. I can only successfully boot Ubuntu if I boot via "Safe mode" and then proceed with normal boot right after. I think it's a missing GPU Driver issue and not a BIOS issue. The bios is quite limited but here settings that might be relevant:

- Fast Boot:    Disabled
- AMD-SVD:      Enabled
- Boot Mode:    UEFI (Grayed-out, can't change)
- Secure Boot:  Disabled
- Current TPM (TCM) State: Not Installed

This is the output when I run `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:c1:00.0
       version: c9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:800-7ff memory:8000000000-800fffffff memory:90000000-901fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90500000-9057ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=3200,2000
```

I believe this means there are no drivers installed, is that correct?
Unfortunately I don't think there are any drivers available for this processor /iGPU, the page [AMD Ryzen™ 7 7840U Drivers & Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-7-processors-radeon-graphics/amd-ryzen-7-7840u) only contains Win 11 or 10 drivers.
[Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-40) are the actual drivers for Ubuntu 22.04 but it's only for dedicated GPU Cards.

I'm not sure what to do next, I think an option I saw somewhere else would be to boot Ubuntu in some other way by default (Maybe in safe mode?), but that doesn't seem ideal. If somebody could help me figure out if I actually need to install correct drivers somehow that would be great!

Just in case here's the output of `sudo lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e8]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e9]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ea]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ea]
00:02.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ee]
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ee]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ea]
00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ef]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ea]
00:04.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ef]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ea]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14eb]
00:08.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14eb]
00:08.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14eb]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f0]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f1]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f2]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f3]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f4]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f5]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f6]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14f7]
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Device [1c5c:1959]
c1:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:15bf] (rev c9)
c1:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
c1:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15c7]
c1:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15b9]
c1:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ba]
c1:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 63)
c1:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
c2:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ec]
c2:00.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1502]
c3:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ec]
c3:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15c0]
c3:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15c1]
c3:00.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1668]
c3:00.6 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1669]
```

boot log output `sudo grep amdgpu ./boot.log | more`:

```
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:amd
gpu_bl0...
[  OK  ] Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of back
light:amdgpu_bl0.
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:amd
gpu_bl0...
[  OK  ] Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of back
light:amdgpu_bl0.
```

`sudo grep amdgpu ./kern.log | more`

```
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.602004] [drm] amdgpu kernel modeset
ting enabled.
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.602509] amdgpu: Ignoring ACPI CRAT 
on non-APU system
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.602512] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table 
created for CPU
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.602519] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU n
ode
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.602648] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: enabli
ng device (0006 -> 0007)
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.604103] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: amdgpu
: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.604105] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-PHXG
ENERIC-001
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.604114] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: [drm:j
peg_v4_0_early_init [amdgpu]] JPEG decode is enabled in VM mode
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.612261] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: Direct
 firmware load for amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes_2.bin failed with error -2
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.612271] [drm] try to fall back to a
mdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes.bin
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.613342] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: vgaarb
: deactivate vga console
Oct  2 13:20:19 Julien-Ubuntu kernel: [    2.613346] amdgpu 0000:c1:00.0: amdgpu
: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature disabled as experimental (default)
```

`sudo grep amdgpu ./kern.log.1 | more`

```
grep: ./kern.log.1: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this and for your help!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148889/discussion-on-question-by-aldinian-ubuntu-22-04-only-boots-in-recovery-mode-mis); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some some digging and I found the following [blog](https://www.phoronix.com/review/amd-ryzen7-7840u). Apparently it is a problem with "GNOME Wayland (Mutter) display". As I'm a beginner with linux, I'm not sure what that means. Anyway, I had to install the kde desktop environment, which works with the 780M iGPU and is just another "skin" for Ubuntu as far as I understand.

Here are the steps I took to solve the issue:

1. Install ubuntu
2. boot into safe mode, and install the kde desktop environment following [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-on-ubuntu/)
3. that's it! the next time you normally boot into ubuntu, it should work without issues

Hopefully Ubuntu will solve this issue soon and this workaround will not be necessary anymore

Comment: You'd have better user experience with Kubuntu